# Beginner here. I need help understanding this callback function better

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I'm learning about promises, and to demonstrate promises, the instructor is first starting with traditional callback example. However, I'm a little confused on the syntax he's using and where some extra parameters seem to have appeared from.

What I'm looking for is a dumbed down explanation to help me wrap my head around it. These are my specific questions:

1. In the first line of the code below, is 'callback' and argument? Is it the name of the function? Or is it something else?
2. On the third and fourth lines, I understand what we're passing in (either the error or the result), but I don't understand where those two parameters came from since we didn't define two parameters anywhere. How does the program know that's okay and not throw an error?

I don't need help with understanding when the function is called, though, because I understand that, it's just some of the stuff in defining the function that I'm confused on. I think it might be the arrow syntax that's throwing me off.

I've tried googling and rewatching the videos over and over again, but still can't grasp what's going on.

```js
const doWorkCallback = (callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       // callback('This is my error', undefined)
       callback(undefined, [1, 4, 7])
    }, 2000)
}

doWorkCallback((error, result) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.log(error)
    }

    console.log(result)

})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is 'callback' an argument?

No, it is the name of the parameter (an argument is what you pass to a function, a parameter is the variable used to access that argument from within the function).

> Is it the name of the function?

Kind of. You can use that Identifier to accesss the variable (/parameter) which holds whatever value you passed to the function as an argument. In your case, you pass a function to it (`(error, result) => ...`), so `callback` will refer to that function.

> On the third and fourth lines, I understand what we're passing in (either the error or the result), but I don't understand where those two parameters came from since we didn't define two parameters anywhere.

You did define a function that takes two parameters (`(error, result) => {`). But that does not matter: You can pass any number of arguments to a function, no matter how many parameters it has. If you pass more arguments than parameters, the arguments will go into nowhere:

```
   alert("used", "ignored");
```

If it is the other way round, parameters that don't receive an argument are `undefined`:

```
  function one(arg1) {  /* arg1 is undefined */ }
  one();
```

> I think it might be the arrow syntax that's throwing me off.

Here is a version just with regular functions:

```
 function doWorkCallback(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      // callback('This is my error', undefined);
      callback(undefined, [1, 4, 7]);
    }, 2000);
  }

  doWorkCallback(function (error, result) {
    if(error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(result);
  })
```

You can read about arrow functions on [Codeburst](https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) ...

Comment: I think what's tripping me up is that I'm used to seeing something like:

```
callback(param1, param1) { do stuff }
```

As opposed to just 
```
(callback)  
```
And then when you get down to callback then you fill in the arguments of "undefined" and [1, 4, 7] 


Does that make sense where my confusion is coming from now?

Comment: As long as that confusion was cleared up now, I don't mind :) Otherwise you have to describe it in another way, I honestly don't really get you ...

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to explain it in a way that makes sense when I'm confused myself, lol. But I assume that once you call `callback` within set timeout and the two arguments, that rather than being callback as a parameter name at this point, it's being treated as a function then, with two parameters.

Comment: Yes, `callback` is a variable, and it evaluates to a value at runtime. That value is a function in your case.

Answer (score 1):

1- Yes, `callback` is the argument of your `doWorkCallback` function.

2- You are passing down a function, not two arguments. That function does receive too arguments which are `error` and `result`.

So, if you go to your doWorkCallback function you see that you will be calling wathever the callback is, undefined as error and `[1, 4, 7]` as result every 2 seconds